# Problems adding JButton to Window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, paintcomponent

I'm now having problems with `JButton`.
My `JButton` will not get added to the `JFrame` or the `JPanel` and it seems to be disabling `paintComponent()` from running.

Here's my JPanel class:

```
public class BLANKScreen extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    public boolean running = false;
    public static ImageIcon greenButton = new ImageIcon("resources/menubuttons/GreenButton.png");
    public static JButton mainMenuPlayButton = new JButton("Play!", greenButton);
    private int fps;
    static BLANKWindow w;
    public int scene = 0;

    public void run() {
        long lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;

        running = true;
        scene = 0;

        while (running) {
            if (scene == 0) {
                addMainMenuButtonsOptions();
            } else if (scene == 1) {

            }

            repaint();

            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000  >= lastFrame) {
                fps = frames;
                frames = 0;
                lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public BLANKScreen (BLANKWindow w) {
        this.w = w;
        this.w.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler(this));
        this.w.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler(this));
        thread.start();
    }

    public class KeyTyped {
        public void keyESC() {
            running = false;
        }

        public void keySpace() {
            if (scene == 0) {
                scene = 1;
            } else if (scene == 1) {
                scene = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MouseClicked { }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, this.w.getWidth(), this.w.getHeight());

        if (scene == 0) {
            int nameLength = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth("BLANK!");
            g.drawString("BLANK!", w.getWidth() / 2 - nameLength / 2, w.getHeight() / 4);
        }
    }

    public void addMainMenuButtonsOptions() {
        mainMenuPlayButton.setActionCommand("/mainMenuPlayButton");
        mainMenuPlayButton.addActionListener(new ActionHandler());

        this.add(mainMenuPlayButton);
        System.out.println("ThingHappend");
    }
}
```

And the `this.add(mainMenuPlayButton);` also doesn't work when I say `w.add(mainMenuPlayButton);`.

Here's my JFrame class:

```
public class BLANKWindow extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BLANKWindow();
    }

    public BLANKWindow() {
        new JFrame();

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width;

        this.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        this.setTitle("BLANK");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);

        BLANKScreen dbs = new BLANKScreen(this);
        this.add(dbs);
    }
}
```

For some reason neither `JButton` nor `paintCompenent()` has decided to load?

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(..)` anytime you override `paintComponent`.

Comment: Is this some kind of psychic JPanel? Does it know where to place the button and its dimension without telling him that? If not, then use `mainMenuPlayButton.setBounds(x, y, width, height);`. Also call `this.setVisible(true);` after adding every element.

Comment: @Vulcan Did that just now. Didn't help in the slightest.

Comment: Don't modify the state of the ui from out the content of th event dispatching thread

Comment: Consider using a CardLayout to switch between screens. Until you fix the swing thread violation, I'm not telling you how to fix it ;)

Comment: @Tom The `BLANKScreen` is using a `FlowLayout`, which take care of the size and position of the component.  Swing components (besides window based components) are visible by default...

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean I am modifying the UI? I'll fix it back but I don't know what you mean. And what do you mean swing thread violation?

Comment: @LordMastodon Yes, but from outside the Event Dispatching Thread.  Swing is not thread safe.  Modifying the UI from outside the EDT will cause no end of potential problems which will be next to near impossible to debug. You clearly have a lack of understanding of how Swing works.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: By modifying the UI from the outside you mean trying to add the button?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, at the core, you have a thread violation of the Swing API and seem to have a lack of knowledge about the basic workings of Swing...Welcome to the danger zone...

Swing is single threaded and is not thread safe.  This means that you should block the EDT but you should also never interact with or modify any UI components from outside the EDT

You need to change your approach.

Swing already has an Event Queue, a thread for processing those events, the Event Dispatching Thread and uses a passive painting algorithm to update the UI (and layout managers).

You need to working within those constraints in order to make it all work.

Instead of trying to switch states within the `BLANKScreen` class, you should start with something like a "menu panel" and a "game panel".

The "menu panel" will display the menu options to the user, the "game panel" will display the game, it will have the game loop and painting logic for the actual game.

Now, you "could" get them to work together, but I think you need to break them apart to start with...it will only complicate the issues...

You could then use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between them.  This will make it easier to change state the visible states.

Also take a look at:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

**Updated...**

The first rule Object Oriented Programming - separation of responsibilities.  An object is responsible for it's job and only it's job.  If you find that your object is trying to do more (like update the frames of game AND display a menu), then you're think along the wrong lines (especially in this case).

You need to separate the menu from the game.  The game has a update mechanism, the menu doesn't care, it doesn't need it, it's updated by the core framework.

The game has user interaction of it's own, so does the menu, but they have different meanings to each other (a mouse click on the menu does something, but in the game it does something else), so they should separated...

The menu and the game probably don't even care about each other, so you could use a controller of some kind, which controls the state between two and facilitates the communication

This is a crude example, I would normally spend more time building better controllers and models, but this is designed to demonstrate the point of the concept, not provide a fully, out of the box, running solution...

[image: Game]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestGameMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGameMenu();
    }

    public TestGameMenu() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainView());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainView extends JPanel {

        private MenuPane menuPane;
        private GamePane gamePane;

        public MainView() {
            setLayout(new CardLayout());
            menuPane = new MenuPane();
            gamePane = new GamePane();

            add(menuPane, "menu");
            add(gamePane, "game");

            menuPane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if ("play".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand()))  {
                        ((CardLayout) getLayout()).show(MainView.this, "game");
                        gamePane.resume();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton playGame;

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            playGame = new JButton("Play My Awesome Game!");
            playGame.setActionCommand("play");
            add(playGame);
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            playGame.addActionListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            playGame.removeActionListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        private Point p;
        private int xDelta;
        private int yDelta;

        private volatile boolean running = true;
        private volatile boolean paused = true;

        private ReentrantLock lckPause;
        private Condition conPause;

        public GamePane() {

            p = new Point(100, 100);
            do {
                xDelta = (int)((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
            } while (xDelta == 0);
            do {
                yDelta = (int)((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
            } while (yDelta == 0);

            lckPause = new ReentrantLock();
            conPause = lckPause.newCondition();
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (running) {
                        while (paused) {
                            lckPause.lock();
                            try {
                                conPause.await();
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            } finally {
                                lckPause.unlock();
                            }
                        }

                        p.x += xDelta;
                        p.y += yDelta;

                        if (p.x < 0) {
                            p.x = 0;
                            xDelta *= -1;
                        } else if (p.x > getWidth()) {
                            p.x = getWidth();
                            xDelta *= -1;
                        }
                        if (p.y < 0) {
                            p.y = 0;
                            yDelta *= -1;
                        } else if (p.y > getHeight()) {
                            p.y = getHeight();
                            yDelta *= -1;
                        }

                        repaint();

                        if (running && !paused) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(40);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            t.start();

        }

        public void pause() {

            if (!paused && running) {

                lckPause.lock();
                try {
                    paused = true;
                } finally {
                    lckPause.unlock();
                }

            }

        }

        public void resume() {

            if (paused && running) {

                lckPause.lock();
                try {
                    paused = false;
                    conPause.signalAll();
                } finally {
                    lckPause.unlock();
                }

            }

        }

        public void stop() {

            if (running) {

                lckPause.lock();
                try {
                    paused = false;
                    running = false;
                    conPause.signalAll();
                } finally {
                    lckPause.unlock();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillOval(p.x - 5, p.y - 5, 10, 10);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this clarified a lot of things. Two questions: Is the name of the EDT simply EDT? And where do I find this EDT?

Comment: The Event Dispatching Thread (EDT) is a construct which is created automatically by the system, normally once a window makes a native connection to the system.  You can run code within the EDT through the use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: So what you're saying is to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater to add my JButton, and then use CardLayout to switch between the panels?

Comment: If your open main window within the context of the EDT, the it doesn't matter, you'll be running within the EDT. You can use the button in combination with the CardLayout to switch between the game panel and menu panel.

Comment: So I can do the same things that I'm using now, with the thread and all, and use SwingUtilities to run through all my run() stuff instead of implementing it inside my JPanel? Then I can just look at the tutorial on how to use CardLayout.

Comment: No, that's my point. Let Swing deal with the Swing stuff. The thread only relates to your Game Panel

Comment: You kinda just confused me.

Comment: Forget about the thread, it's the key to your problem.  Start by getting a basic UI with two panels, one that acts as the menu and one that is the place holder for the game panel.  Get it so you can switch between these two.  Once you have that, then you can introduce the game panel, which will have it's game loop thread.  DO NOT try and control UI, that's not how this works.  You are working inside and existing framework, you need to play by it's rules

Comment: Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: I can't use the Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing tutorial because that uses NetBeans and that is an IDE I do not like. And I'm still confused about the whole Runnable thing.

Comment: Of course you can, it might "suggest" using Netbeans form designer, but it's not a requirement, in fact, all the code examples are hand coded.  You need to understand how Swing works, that's the point

Comment: I changed up the way the program works; There's a new comment with the changed files. I accommodated CardLayout and tried to accommodate Swing, however I'm still confused about what to do with my Thread and with the code inside my run() method in the Screen class.

Comment: Your new edit helped a lot, however I plan on having a lot more complicated things, so a single file is not going to cut it.

Comment: It is an example. To make it easier to post, I put everything in a single class. Perhaps if you expanded the idea to fit your needs rather then looking for a complete solution you would find a resolution to your issues. Normally, I would use some kind of model to control the navigation and not use a component as the core econtroller, buts it's just example to demonstrate the basic concept

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer 's comment has the answer. But aside from the severe threading problem, you appear to be adding the button many times to the container. As far as I can tell, `addMainMenuButtonsOptions` is called every 2 ms until a key is pressed. (Although you don't show the code that uses the class `KeyTyped`, I assume you have bound it to a key listener?).

A smaller point: Have you considered using `setBackground` and `setOpaque` in the constructor, instead of calling `clearRect` manually?

Also as @Tom pointed out, it looks like you are using a default layout so the (multiple?) buttons will probably float to the top - is that what you want?

Comment: Actually, because the OP is adding the same instance of the component to the container, it will only ever be added once...

Comment: No, I'm going to use setBounds(). Also, what do you mean by I have a key bound to it?

Comment: @LordMastodon `BLANKScreen` is under the management of a layout manager, even if you set it `null`, which isn't advisable, it will not make any difference, you have other problems that aren't associated with adding the component to the main few.  You're trying to "control" how Swing works, but Swing already has a event and painting process, you need to work within those boundaries or it simply isn't going to work